# Soundcloud Download

Tags: java

Всем привет! Делаю бота-мультизагрузчика, по-тихоньку прорываюсь среди защит разных сервисов... Вопрос вот в чем:
Как скачать трек с soundcloud? Если по-другим сервисам я хотя бы что-то находил, то тут -  вообще нуль. Лучше всего, конечно, решение под Java. 
Заранее спасибо!